# Docker services in image not launching

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am new to docker. I've prepared a docker image. On it, I've installed application as user root. On launch, the root .bashrc contains some lines that be execute. On the machine where I prepare the image, all was running correcting. I saved the image as a tar with the command docker save to a tar file. Using the tar file, I loaded the image on another machine. Using docker, when I start the image using the command docker run, it doesn't execute the root .bashrc. When I execute it manually using source .bashrc it executes but there are services which fails. Any idea why this is happening ? Because I was thinking that the moment you have the image, you load the image in a container, it is expected to work similarly everywhere.

Comment: Do you happen to be launching the container with -it? I think the interactive shell is needed to tell bash to read .bashrc

Comment: yes i do, that's my command; docker run -i -t -p 3000:3000 cc6dfffad014